# Remove border displayed behind another element (Pie/Doughnut)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a pie where the center and each pie piece are independent. The center is static and its z-index is the highest inside the parent. Behind this center, individual pieces of the pie are generated. Both the center and the individual pieces of the Pie have transparent backgrounds because an image is displayed at the body level.

When hovering over an individual pie piece, the border of it can be seen behind the static center. I need to remove only the section of the border displayed behind the static center of the pie while keeping the transparent background. I have been looking at a partial border display and how to create doughnuts but the normal approach is not sufficient for this.

In the picture below, I need to remove the part of the lines inside the red section, while keeping the background transparent for all the elements.

[image]

Below is the basic structure of the pie. I kept it simple, as the elements of the pie are dynamically generated.

```
<body>
   <div class="pie">
         <div class="pie-center">
              <div></div>
         </div>
         <div class="pie-children">
              <div class="pie-children__1"></div>
              <div class="pie-children__2"></div>
              <div class="pie-children__3"></div>
              <div class="pie-children__4"></div>
         </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: url(https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/5517182.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.pie {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 48px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 50rem;
    border: 1px solid red;
    z-index:100;
}

.pie-center {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}

.pie-center>div {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 50rem;
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 100;
}

.pie-children{
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1em auto;
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index:1;
}

.pie-children__1, .pie-children__2, .pie-children__3, .pie-children__4{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.pie-children__1{transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(0deg)}
.pie-children__2 {transform: rotate(90deg) skewY(0deg)}
.pie-children__3 {transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(0deg)}
.pie-children__4 {transform: rotate(270deg) skewY(0deg)}

.pie-children__1:hover, .pie-children__2:hover, .pie-children__3:hover, .pie-children__4:hover{
cursor:pointer;
background-color:white;
}
```

Fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/jsandler/u34r8x9d/17/

Comment: Can you show us the CSS you have so far, to make it a bit clearer when the borders come in and out.

Comment: @AHaworth I have attached the CSS to the original question

Comment: I can’t see how the CSS you provide can produce a pie chart - how are the segments given their ‘cake slice’ shape?

Comment: @AHaworth I have attached the fiddle and updated the CSS. Hope this is more useful.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it doesn’t resemble a pie chart. How do you make segments, even just the simplest example of four?

Comment: I modify each child from its origin, then rotate them to their designated position. Each element has to remain separated because I'm creating them dynamically. Sometimes there are 3,4,5 or more elements on display. I use the skewY() to center the text inside each element. The example of 4 is the simplest one, fewer or more elements become more complex. I was hoping if there is some kind of filter or something that can be applied that will cut out whatever is overlap between one element that is on top of the other, but at the same time leave the transparent background.

Comment: Sorry to come back on this, but your code does not create a pie chart, how do you get the segments in the right position, at the moment they drop too far down on the aspect ratios I've tried.

Answer (score 2):

I got confused by the method used to create segments given in the question as it didn't seem to put them in the right place vertically, at least on the viewport aspect ratios that I tried.

This snippet takes a slightly different approach. Each segment is still a div but each is formed by using clip-path to get the right shape and then rotating it an amount which depends on how many segments there are. The CSS variable --num is set to the number of segments - set to 5 in this example.

To get the 'border' on each a before pseudo element is placed on the 'leftmost' side of each segment. It is solid black for one part but the bit that would overlap the inner circle is made transparent.

The final result is:

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pie {
  --num: 5;
  /* the number of slices */
  --deg: calc(360deg / var(--num));
  /* the number of degrees occupied by each slice */
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 2px black;
  position: relative;
  clip-path: circle(50%);
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1024/768);
  background-size: cover;
}

.pie>* {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.pie-center {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 2px black solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pie-children {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.pie-children>* {
  background-color: transparent;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  --angle: calc(((var(--n) - 1) * var(--deg)) + 45deg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(var(--angle));
}

.pie-children>*::before {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: linear-gradient(black 0 70%, transparent 70% 100%);
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.pie-children>*:nth-child(1) {
  --n: 1;
}

.pie-children>*:nth-child(2) {
  --n: 2;
}

.pie-children>*:nth-child(3) {
  --n: 3;
}

.pie-children>*:nth-child(4) {
  --n: 4;
}

.pie-children>*:nth-child(5) {
  --n: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="pie">
  <div class="pie-center"></div>
  <div class="pie-children">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks really good, using this approach how would you center the text inside of each child?

Comment: What do you require as centering? Is the text to go radially or is it to be turned so it’s the right way up for reading?

Comment: Both, currently I use a combination of skewY and rotation to place the text in the center of each child. One issue I was dealing with was to flip the text upside down. I was using scale(-1, -1) but the text was getting displaced

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to set up the text in your approach?

Comment: Your question does not mention anything about text. Perhaps you could add that requirement to this question (or start another one) making it absolutely clear what orientation the text is to have. I do not think the method in my answer is very suitable for the text needing to change ('flip') past 180deg, assuming that is what you want. Some Javascript is probably needed as CSS itself cannot deal with doing calculations involving a bit of trigonometry.

Answer (score 1):

The svg gods have descended upon you. All you need to do is create an svg mask for the middle circle and position fix the background image twice. Amen.

This is what I changed in your fiddle...

```
body {
  background: url(https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/5517182.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.pie.ctr {
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  top: 0;
  mask: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100"/></svg>');
  background: url(https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/5517182.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin-top: -100%;
}

<div class="pie">
  <div class="pie-center">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="pie-children">
    <div class="pie-children__1"></div>
    <div class="pie-children__2"></div>
    <div class="pie-children__3"></div>
    <div class="pie-children__4"></div>
  </div>     
</div>
<div class="pie ctr"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ecno6y38/

Comment: oh god jottin, can you please explain a little bit more how the mask and the double background image position fix make it work? It works amazing, I just want to understand more about it.

Comment: Also, this answer will not work for me because the background is dynamic as well. I have a water effect and other things going on at the back over the image background. Therefore setting the image at the top of other elements is not a viable approach.

Comment: We are just aligning the two bkgd images in the stacking order (one on top of another) and clipping the outside portion beyond the red circle of the top-most image. This is a faux inverted mask technique with svg. There is probably still a way to get the two bkgd images to align even if they are set to cover but that may require some javascript.